# Direct2D Error NO_HARDWARE_DEVICE When Injecting Dll Into Another Process

Tags: c++, winapi, direct2d, dll-injection, direct3d11

I have a native target application that renders something by using `Direct3D11`. I want to extend the functionality of the target by injecting a DLL and hooking some APIs(not important to mention but it is XInputGetState). When DLL is injected, it also creates a window and provides some useful information. To render the information in the window, I use `Direct2D`, but after injecting the DLL, in another process's address space, calling the `ID2D1Factory::CreateHwndRenderTarget` **fails** with the error code [`D2DERR_NO_HARDWARE_DEVICE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/direct2d-error-codes) and doesn't create the `ID2D1HwndRenderTarget` object. The Factory object is created successfully and it is not NULL.

When I change the project type from `Dynamic Link Library(.dll)` to `Application(.exe)` and the entry point from `DllMain` to `main` and run it as a separate console application, the `ID2D1Factory::CreateHwndRenderTarget` **succeeds**.

I think that the problem causes by the existence of a created Direct3D11 Device already, but I am not sure.

Is there documentation about that? How can I solve the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put directly the D2D creating function into new thread by CreateThread in DllMain.